# How to Validate the future date for card expiry in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to add validation for card expiry where I need to show an error message if the card is about to expire within 3 month's from current date

ex:

```
(month/year)1221 input --> false (invalid)
1121 input --> false (invalid)
122 input --> false (invalid)
221 input --> true (valid) 
222 input --> true (valid)
```

From the backend this is the value I am getting
value = 424 --> 4 is the month and 24 is the year which is valid and
if from backend I am getting 1121 ---> 11 is the month and 21 is the year which is invalid

How to validate if the date 1121 is within 3 months?

Below is the solution I am using but I don't find other solutions

```js
const d = new Date();
let today = d.getDate();
expValue = 424;
const originalValue = expValue.toString().split(/(?=(?:.{2})+$)/g);
if (
  originalValue[0] >= today.month.toString() + 3 ||
  originalValue[1] === today.year.toString()
) {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
    '<span class="text-danger">' +
    ('0' + originalValue[0]).slice(-2) +
    '/' +
    originalValue[1] +
    '</span>'
  );
} else {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
    ('0' + originalValue[0]).slice(-2) + '/' + originalValue[1]
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the input into dates, or how to do the calculation, or both?

Comment: You may need to create a formula for counting the numbers without the last 2 digits, so if you have 424, set the last two digits as a variable, y and then add 3 to the remaining digits, with an if clause for a number over 12 that increments the y value, this should give you 724, Then create a date of now and get the month and year, compare those.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I have used the above solution to validate and calculate which is not working

Comment: I had already given an answer for the inputs that were there when I started, but I went back and edited it for two different scenarios, either a date that is in this format m/y or one that is in this format: my.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the original inputs you gave, you can do something like this:

```js
let inputs = ['12/21', '11/21', '01/22', '02/21', '12/22'];

const parseDate =(e)=>{ return new Date(e.replace('/', '/1/')); };

const getDiff = (e)=>{ 
  let curr = new Date();
  let dt = parseDate(e);
  return (dt.getMonth() - curr.getMonth() + 
  (12 * (dt.getYear() - curr.getYear()))) > 3;
}

inputs.forEach(el=>console.log(`${el} >> ${getDiff(el)}`));
```

If your inputs are in a different format or if you have to account for strings that aren't always the same length you might have to adjust the parseDate function.  If you are working with a variable length string without the included "/", then you might try something like this, using the new inputs you gave:

```js
let inputs = ['1221', '1121', '122', '221', '222'];

const parseDate =(e)=>{ 
  if(e.length==3) { e = '0'+e; }
  return new Date(`${e.substring(0,2)}/1/${e.slice(-2)}`); 
};

const getDiff = (e)=>{ 
  let curr = new Date();
  let dt = parseDate(e);
  return (dt.getMonth() - curr.getMonth() + 
  (12 * (dt.getYear() - curr.getYear()))) > 3;
}

inputs.forEach(el=>console.log(`${el} >> ${getDiff(el)}`));
```

I modify the parseDate function to pad the string if the length  is 3 (I think it's always going to be 3 or 4), then create a date from the first two characters and the last two characters, then return that, and everything else is the same.

Comment: 221 >> false should be valid right

Comment: 2/21 is in the past, so it should be invalid, corect?

Comment: oh sorry yes its correct

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to go at this is to translate dates into units that are suited to the problem. JS date `getYear()` gives months since 1990, and that's a practically useful common unit.

Put the input string date and the current date into units of months since 1990, then compare...

```js
const monthsSince1900 = string => {
  let chars = string.split('');
  let month = +chars.slice(0, -2).join('');
  let year = +chars.slice(-2).join('');
  return 12 * (100 + year) + month
};

const currentMonthsSince1990 = () => {
  let d = new Date();
  return 12 * d.getYear() + d.getMonth() + 1;
}

const isExpiryValid = string => {
  let now = currentMonthsSince1990()
  let exp = monthsSince1900(string);
  return exp > now + 3
}

console.log(isExpiryValid('1121'));  // 11/21 will expire soon
console.log(isExpiryValid('1221'));  // 12/21 will expire soon
console.log(isExpiryValid('122'));   // 1/22 will expire soon
console.log(isExpiryValid('222'));   // 2/22 is good
console.log(isExpiryValid('322'));   // 3/22 is good
```